# itunes（i can not find the somewhere to remove the current app being rejected）

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Some days before.I got the app rejected in Itunes.Today i want to remove the current rejected version.But the itunes has some big changes.i can not find the place to remove the Current.

i find the Official Helps:

Removing the current build.

Open the App Details page for the app, as described in To open the App Details page for an app.
On Versions, scroll down to the Build section.
Click the delete icon  ../Art/DeleteIcon_2x.png hovering at the right of the build number. Deleting it does not remove the build from the list of uploaded builds; it just means the build is no longer the current build for that app release.
Changing builds. You can set and change the current build as often as you want by repeating the steps above.

But actually i found nothing except this:

Submit your builds using Xcode 5.1.1 or later, or Application Loader 2.9.1 or later.

Who can tell me how to remove the current version.thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue when it was rejected.

After I upload new build using Xcode5.1.1, I can see our new build for store submission in the build section. So upload new build from xcode and wait for some time, then you can see that in the build section.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove version go to app details page bottom "Submit your builds using Xcode 5.1.1 or later, or Application Loader 2.9.1 or later" left side red color button.